# Can Silverlight host a .NET Winforms User Control?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have a user control written for .NET Winforms.   Is it possible to host this control from within Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Silverlight is a cut down, cross platform clr that does not do winforms. Winforms is very much linked to windows' built in gui primitives.

Comment: It is possible to use WinForms controls on WPF, but you run into airspace issues.

Comment: True, in case of the full-blown clr. I am only expaining why you can't in wpf.